# Is there a reason why Ilsa Faust and Julia Hunt look alike?

Tags: casting, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-rogue-nation, mission-impossible-fallout

When watching *Mission: Impossible - Rogue Nation* I was constantly thinking about how similar the two characters look with their darker colored hair, similar complexion and freckles.

When I saw the trailers for *Fallout* I was excited because Julia looked like she would play a major part in the movie because I mistook Rebecca Ferguson for Michelle Monaghan in almost every scene. Although Ilsa/Rebecca's hair is lighter in *Fallout* than it is in *Rogue Nation*, and her face is thinner than Julia/Michelle, there is still a strong resemblance which you would think casting directors would try and avoid.

Is this resemblance intentional?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I tweeted about this 18 months ago! Same confusion! https://twitter.com/BrettFromLA/status/824674575745179649

Comment: My guess is that it thematic choice, which then allows the audience to understand what what Ethan may see in Faust, his wife and everything she isn't, but potentially could be. I haven't seen Fallout though to see where their relationship goes. Often times in TV series there are characters that look, behave, or take on similar roles of character that came before (Ie: Colony, Dexter) -- it's a way to create an aesthetic motif and/or ultimately create a theme through incarnates/counterparts. I would presume in Ethan Hunt's case it's about being tempted.

Comment: @DarthLocke that could be an answer

Comment: I would feel better about it, if I would have seen the film just so I could make better comparisons to that idea, but without doing so, it would be a bit of a  conseat.

Comment: The resemblance was very confusing for the plot of the film with these characters. They almost looked like twins, as I truly believed the director had chosen to use the same actress for both roles. To create some sort of "motif" that was discussed in an earlier post. However, it could've been an easy fix by coloring the hair of one of the actresses, in order to distinguish them. Otherwise, it was very difficult to tell them apart.

Comment: I believe that it hints at the fact that Ethan loves both Ilsa and Julia as @Darth Locke has already said. However, this resemblance might also not be intentional. What is for sure though is that many viewers (myself included) can't really tell them apart throughout the film and this can make the plot more difficult to follow.

Comment: Strangely, I confused Isla Faust with the White Widow